# how to customize a navigation menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I want to know how can I customize a navigation menu in wordpress. I want to be able to change the look and contents of the navigation menu according to my need.I searched for plugins but none matches with the requirement. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The menu is built up by the pages that you create. All the other stuff that you see are made up from widgets which you can drag and drop in the widgets menu.

So what are your plans exactly and what is the url so we can help a little bit better?

Comment: I want to have a menu like this http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-mega-menu-plugin/ . I tried to install the plugin in my latest wordpress, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions?

== Installation ==

1. Upload the plugin through `Plugins > Add New > Upload` interface or upload `jquery-mega-menu` folder to the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory
2. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress
3. In the widgets section, select the jQuery mega menu widget and add to one of your widget areas
4. Select one of the WP menus, set the required settings and save your widget